# Xpages REST Service does not recompute view name hen partialRefresh is done on parent panel

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Want to check if rest service control does not honour context.getSubmittedValue() for viewName property? 
REST Service view name is not being computed when partialRefresh is done on parent panel.
I am trying to load different views (DataTable used for display) and need to work with JSON object. However, when I click on accordion entry which updates a panel in another custom control, I can see submitted value changing using computed field but my REST service control will still return old data. Here is the code should you want to have a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:panel id="panelMiddle">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:context.getSubmittedValue()}"></xp:text>

        <xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="data" preventDojoStore="true" state="false">
            <xe:this.service>
                <xe:viewItemFileService defaultColumns="true" contentType="application/json" compact="true" systemColumns="0">
                    <xe:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v = context.getSubmittedValue();
if (null == v){
    v = application.getString("defaultView");
}
}]]></xe:this.viewName>
                    <xe:this.count><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var v = context.getSubmittedValue();
if (null == v){
    v = application.getString("defaultView");
}
database.getView(v).getEntryCount();
}]]></xe:this.count>
                </xe:viewItemFileService>
            </xe:this.service>
        </xe:restService>
        <div id="demo"></div>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"New.xsp/data",
        dataType:"json",
        success:
            function(data){
                var colHeaders = [];
                var tarr = [];
                $.each(data.items[0], function (key, val) {
                    if(key.indexOf("@")==-1){
                        colHeaders.push({"title":key});
                        //colHeaders.push({"data":key});
                    }
                });
                $.each(data.items,function(v,i){
                    var temp = [];
                    $.each(i,function(k,vv){
                        if(k.indexOf("@")==-1){temp.push(vv)};
                    })
                    tarr.push(temp);
                })  
                $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example"></table>' );

                $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "data": tarr,
                    "columns": colHeaders
                } );  
            }

    });

});]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial with scope variables and computed fields, found out that only sessionScope works in this scenario. Not sure if this is an ideal solution as people may open more than one tab in a browser and it may cause conflicts.
Ideas are welcome.